# How does one atomically change a symlink to a directory in busybox?

Tags: linux, directory, symlink, busybox

I am trying to (as close as possibly) atomically change a symlink. I've tried:

```
ln -sf other_dir existing_symlink
```

That just put the new symlink in the directory that existing_symlink pointed to.

```
ln -sf other_dir new_symlink
mv -f new_symlink existing_symlink
```

That did the same thing: it moved the symlink into the directory.

```
cp -s other_dir existing_symlink
```

It refuses because it's a directory.

I've read that `mv -T` is was made for this, but busybox doesn't have the `-T` flag.

Comment: Busybox has had the `mv -T` option since 1.34.0, see https://www.busybox.net/ and https://git.busybox.net/busybox/commit/coreutils/mv.c?id=91bc01c5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how you can get atomic operation.  The man page for `symlink(2)` says it gives `EEXIST` if the target already exists. If the kernel doesn't support atomic operation, your userland limitations are irrelevant.

I also don't see how `mv -T` helps, even if you have it.  Try it on a regular Linux box, one with GNU mv:

```
$ mkdir a b
$ ln -s a z
$ mv -T b z
mv: cannot overwrite non-directory `z' with directory `b'
```

I think you're going to have to do this in two steps: remove the old symlink and recreate it.

Comment: Indeed, there is unfortunately no way you can modify a symbolic atomically. The best you can do is remove the old link and create a new one. GNU coreutils has an option to do this with a single command (`ln -snf`), but there are still two system calls under the hood.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' It looks like it *is* possible using the 2 techniques in the other answers. 1) use rename system call with `mv -T`, or 2) use mv to move the new symlink with the correct (target) name already, located in a temp dir in the same filesystem as the target dir, to the target *dir* (containing the target symlink).

Answer (score 54):

This **can** indeed be done atomically with `rename(2)`, by first creating the new symlink under a temporary name and then cleanly overwriting the old symlink in one go. As the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/rename) states:

> If *newpath* refers to a symbolic link the link will be overwritten.

In the shell, you would do this with `mv -T` as follows:

```
$ mkdir a b
$ ln -s a z
$ ln -s b z.new
$ mv -T z.new z
```

You can `strace` that last command to make sure it is indeed using `rename(2)` under the hood:

```
$ strace mv -T z.new z
lstat64("z.new", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=1, ...}) = 0
lstat64("z", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=1, ...}) = 0
rename("z.new", "z")                    = 0
```

Note that in the above, both `mv -T` and `strace` are Linux-specific.

On FreeBSD, use `mv -h` alternately.

Comment: Very nice! It might be helpful to say that at the end you have a link from z to b!

Comment: For an OS-independent solution use a scripting language which is capable to to use the `rename` syscall directly instead of `mv -h` or `mv -T`. For example with Perl: `perl -e 'rename "z.new", "z" or die $!'`

Answer (score 12):

Picking up where Arto left off here, this is entirely possible, even without `mv -T`, you just need to create a new symlink with the same name as the target directory and `mv` it into the parent directory of your target:

```
mkdir -p tmp/real_dir1 tmp/real_dir2
touch tmp/real_dir1/a tmp/real_dir2/a
# start with ./target_dir pointing to tmp/real_dir1
ln -s tmp/real_dir1 target_dir
# create a symlink named target_dir in tmp, pointing to real_dir2
ln -sf tmp/real_dir2 tmp/target_dir
# atomically mv it into ./ replacing ./target_dir
mv tmp/target_dir ./
```

Code example taken via (http://axialcorps.wordpress.com/2013/07/03/atomically-replacing-files-and-directories/)

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried `ln -snf`?

The option `-n` overwrites the destination rather than writing under it when the destination is a symbolic link to a directory.

Cheers

Comment: `ln -snf` is not atomic: it unlinks the destination, then creates the desired symlink.

Comment: Given that the OP was interested in getting "as close as possib[e]" to atomically changing a symlink, this is a perfectly reasonable answer. If there is a better one that can get closer (or be) atomic, that one can be accepted. I don't think there's a need to downvote.

Comment: Not sure for busybox, but I have confirmed by strace that on modern linux distribution such as Ubuntu Bionic, the ln -snf works atomically, it does not call unlink, it will do actually "ln -s source a_tmp_file && mv -T a_tmp_file symlink"