# Is there way to replace value of symbolic link?

Tags: symlink, ln

Is there a way to replace the value of a symbolic link?

For example, I want to change a symbolic link from this:

```
first -> /home/username/foo/very/long/directories/that/I/do/not/want/to/type/again
```

to this:

```
second -> /home/username/bar/very/long/directories/that/I/do/not/want/to/type/again
```

I want to change only `foo` to `bar`.

Of course I can create a link again, but if it is possible to replace the value of the link, it becomes easier.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, IMO. The other one just talks about repointing a symlink. This question is talking about modifying just a part of the symlink. That responses makes no mention of readlink.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the `-f`, `--force` option of `ln` to have it remove the existing symlink before creating the new one. If the destination is a directory, you need to add the `-n`, `--no-dereference` option to tell `ln` to treat the symlink as a normal file.

```
ln -sfn target existing_link
```

However, this operation is not atomic, as `ln` will `unlink()` the old symlink before calling `symlink()`, so technically it doesn't count as changing the value of the link. If you care about this distinction, then the answer is no, you can't change the value of an existing symlink.

That said, you can do something like the following to create a new symlink, changing part of the old link value:

```
  ln -sfn "$(readlink existing_link | sed s/foo/bar/)" "existing_symlink"
```

Comment: To atomically change the destination of a symlink, see this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6786.

Answer (score 1):

```
second -> /home/username/bar/very/long/directories/that/I/do/not/want/to/type/again
```

If you are running inside X:

```
stat second
```

Will print the link and some other information.  Type `ln -s`, then highlight `/home/username/bar/very/long/directories/that/I/do/not/want/to/type/again` with the mouse cursor.  Press the middle button (or both buttons if you only have two).  The long line you didn't want to type again will be pasted at the text cursor.

If you aren't in X, you can do the same thing by installing `gpm`.